# What to do if one condition fails in AND operation but still have to pick the records ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to pick only those records with whom datediff between OPENINGDATE and GETDATE() is <=3 and also OPENINGTIME is greater than current time. That's ok and working but the another scenario is if OPENINGTIME gets less than Current Time then it still should pick the records if DATEDIFF condition remains true.

Currently it fails if only opening time gets lower than current time.

Code:

```
Declare @NotificationAllowed bit
    Set @NotificationAllowed= ISNULL((Select NotificationAllowed from Roles where RoleID= @RoleID),0)

    IF @NotificationAllowed=1
    BEGIN
        Select  @NotificationAllowed as IsAllowed, Works.NIT_No, Works.WorkNo, Works.WorkName, DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) as TotalDaysRemaining 
                ,Convert(varchar(11), Works.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate
        from Works
        Where DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) <=3
        AND 
        DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) >=0
        AND 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), Works.OpeningTime, 108) >  CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108) 
        AND
        Works.Organization_ID= Case When @RoleID=1  then Works.Organization_ID ELSE @OrgID end 
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select  0 as IsAllowed, '' AS NIT_No, ''  AS WorkNo, '' AS WorkName, '' as TotalDaysRemaining, null as OpeningDate
    END
```

Help me with it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you just use a combination of AND and OR with the conditions you want to check? You can simply write the same condition twice in an Expression like "(A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (NOT B AND C)".

Comment: As an aside, converting your dates to text to compare them add unnecessary work. Since 2008, this has worked: `cast([MyDate] as time)`

Answer (score 0):

```html
   Declare @NotificationAllowed bit
    Set @NotificationAllowed= ISNULL((Select NotificationAllowed from Roles where RoleID= @RoleID),0)

    IF @NotificationAllowed=1
    BEGIN
        Select  @NotificationAllowed as IsAllowed, Works.NIT_No, Works.WorkNo, Works.WorkName, DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) as TotalDaysRemaining 
                ,Convert(varchar(11), Works.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate
        from Works
        Where DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) Between 0 AND  3
        AND 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), Works.OpeningTime, 108) >  CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108) 
  AND
        Works.Organization_ID= Case When @RoleID=1  then Works.Organization_ID ELSE @OrgID end 
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select  0 as IsAllowed, '' AS NIT_No, ''  AS WorkNo, '' AS WorkName, '' as TotalDaysRemaining, null as OpeningDate
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @NotificationAllowed bit
    Set @NotificationAllowed= ISNULL((Select NotificationAllowed from Roles where RoleID= @RoleID),0)

    IF @NotificationAllowed=1
    BEGIN
        Select  @NotificationAllowed as IsAllowed, Works.NIT_No, Works.WorkNo, Works.WorkName, DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) as TotalDaysRemaining 
                ,Convert(varchar(11), Works.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate
        from Works
        Where (DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) BETWEEN 0 and 3
        OR
        CONVERT(varchar(5), Works.OpeningTime, 108) >  CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108)) 
        AND
        Works.Organization_ID= Case When @RoleID=1  then Works.Organization_ID ELSE @OrgID end 
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select  0 as IsAllowed, '' AS NIT_No, ''  AS WorkNo, '' AS WorkName, '' as TotalDaysRemaining, null as OpeningDate
    END
```

Just combine those two date conditions with OR. I also changed that Datediff fucntion to make it without another and not to make it more complicated.